# Is the a way to use prefix AND ping for commands?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've decided to create a much more helpful bot, and I would like to allow the commands to be activated in two ways: `x.` which is the default prefix and `@xubot`, aka pinging the bot.

My commands are set out like this:

```py
# sidenote: this is not an actual command ;)

pref = 'x.'
client = Bot(command_prefix=pref)

@client.command(name="example",
               pass_ctx=True)
async def example(ctx, type=""):
    # the "type" parameter is used so i can check if it is "help" and display an embed
    await ctx.send("Test!")
```

However, I can only activate the commands with my prefix, `x.`

I would like for `@xubot example` to run the command, as well as `x.example`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the [`commands.when_mentioned_or`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or) function as your prefix:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, when_mentioned_or

bot = Bot(command_prefix=when_mentioned_or("x."))

...
```